# Polymer Element not registered in polymer from string/text

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

Can someone help me with stating what am I doing wrong in this example -- http://jsbin.com/bekoxo/2/edit?html,output#H:L23

The screenshot for the chrome inspector is at -
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6uua7h714h2otg/Screenshot%202014-10-13%2001.32.54.png?dl=0

I can figure out that the element (appler-page) is not registered successfully, template shows document-fragment instead of desired shadow-root

the 2nd element, where polymer definition is part of the markup(same markup) is rendered successfully.

Can someone point out what am I missing in order to make the first part of example also work.

(which is creating an element  via javascript and using it immediately)

EDIT --- problem code below

```
<head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.3/platform.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.3/polymer.js"></script>
<meta name="description" content="problem with dynamically building a polymer element" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>  
var scr = '<polymer-element name="appler-page"><template>template content {{test}}</template><script>var proxymodel = {};proxymodel["test"] = "testfie" ;'+
    'Polymer(proxymodel);<\/script><\/polymer-element><appler-page><\/appler-page>';
  $(document).ready(function(){
  document.getElementById("fie").onclick = function(){
   var divel = document.createElement("div");
    divel.innerHTML = scr;

    document.querySelector(".polymerized").innerHTML = "";
    document.querySelector(".polymerized").appendChild(divel);
}

  });
  </script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="button" id="fie" value="fie"/>
  <div class="polymerized">before content</div>
```

EDIT -- A better jsbin for the problem

http://jsbin.com/bekoxo/2/edit?html,output#H:L23

Comment: My internet is super slow, can you isolate the problematic code and post it here on stackoverflow or reproduce it on a small example, please?

Comment: Hi Winchestro - the jsbin link above is the smallest example i came up with. On click of the first button 'fie' , the polymer element is not registered from the string.

Comment: I mean jsbin takes ages to load with slow internet, probably it even timed out, I closed after like a few minutes :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another instance of staying up with the latest Polymer version I found.

here's the working piece of code that may help anyone else if they are attempting the same thing.

I switched to Polymer-project.org addresses for the imports and it worked.

http://jsbin.com/bekoxo/14/edit?html,output#H:L23

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way in which you can register your element imperatively (which, I believe is what your first element is trying to do). I've simplified your example a bit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import"
          href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <script>
      Polymer('appler-page', {test: 'testfile'});
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.innerHTML = '\
<polymer-element name="appler-page">\
  <template>template content {{test}}</template>\
</polymer-element>';
      document.body.appendChild(el);
    </script>
    <appler-page></appler-page>
  </body>
</html>
```

See http://jsbin.com/qifupa/edit

Comment: Thanks Shailen Tuli. However, this changes things. I did see this earlier too. In my case, the entire polymer-element definition data needs to be coming as a text.

Here - in the version you provided, we need to be having the script as part of markup. I was looking for away around that.